# Combining GCD and congruences

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility, congruences

Let $a, b, m, k \in \Bbb Z$ such that $m\ge2$ and $k\not=0$. Let $d=\gcd(k,m)$. Prove that if $a\equiv b\pmod m$ and $k$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$, then ${\frac ak}\equiv {\frac bk}\pmod {\frac md}$.

Any ideas? I'm really stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, $\displaystyle {\frac ad}\equiv {\frac bd}\pmod {\frac md}$.

Now, write $k=dk'$ and $m=dm'$, with $\gcd(k',m')=1$.

Then
$\displaystyle
\frac{ak'}{k}=\frac{ak'}{dk'}=\frac{a}{d}
\equiv
\frac{b}{d} = \frac{bk'}{dk'} = \frac{bk'}{k}\pmod {m'}$.

Finally, $\gcd(k',m')=1$ allows us to cancel $k'$ on both sides of
$\displaystyle
\frac{ak'}{k}
\equiv
\frac{bk'}{k}\pmod {m'}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $k$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$, therefore $\exists \, p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that 
$$a=pk \qquad b=qk$$
Then $a \equiv b \pmod{m}$ implies that $m | (a-b)$, hence $m | k(p-q)$. Thus $m/d$ divides $k/d(p-q)$. But $\gcd(\frac{m}{d}, \frac{k}{d})=1$. Therefore
$$m/d \quad \text{ divides } \quad (p-q).$$
This gives us
$$p \equiv q \pmod{\frac{m}{d}}.$$
Now multiply both sides by $k$ and the congruence still holds, giving us
$$a \equiv b \pmod{\frac{m}{d}}.$$